# Why /bin/bash is default process in docker container?

Tags: docker

I can't understand some thing:

```
docker run -d ubuntu
```

For very short time using `docker ps` I have been able to see:

```
bcf2c7153526        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         4 seconds ago       Up Less than a second                       pensive_jepsen
```

Why `/bin/bash` was chosen command ? After all I didn't choose it.

Comment: Because the Dockerfile says so.

Comment: entrypoint or cmd ?

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in the `Dockerfile` of the `ubuntu` image.

```
# overwrite this with 'CMD []' in a dependent Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

1. https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/
2. https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/46511cf49ad5d2628f3e8d88e1f8b18699a3ad8f/xenial/Dockerfile#L48